# What format does the highcharts js library accept for dates?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and cannot figure out what the date input should be from rails dates to the highcharts accepted format for dates.

In my migration file i am storing the date like this:

```
t.date :consumption_date
```

The value gets stored in this format "2012-03-25", and going to the terminal and finding the record i get this:

```
=>  Sat, 31 Mar 2012
```

When the chart renders, the individual points display **Invalid date**. The following array gets output to highcharts to render

```
[[Sun, 25 Mar 2012, 1158], [Sat, 31 Mar 2012, 1200]]
```

The format that highcharts uses in one of their demo charts, when the data is submitted in jquery is of the form:

```
[[Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ], [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ]]
```

How can i get rid of the invalid date, by submitting the correct date format to highcharts.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Internally Highcharts uses javascript Date numbers (the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970) to represent dates. See [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

To get dates on an axis you will first need to set the axis type to 'datetime':

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
}
```

You have a few options when specifying the series data (all three examples produce the same chart):

1. Setting a start point and using a fixed interval between points

   ```
   pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 2, 6, 10),
   pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60,
   data: [5, 6, 4]
   ```
2. Specifying the exact date using the Date.UTC method. This way its readable for humans:

   ```
   data: [
       [Date.UTC(2012, 2, 6, 10), 5], 
       [Date.UTC(2012, 2, 6, 11), 6], 
       [Date.UTC(2012, 2, 6, 12), 4]]
   ```
3. Or specifying the epoch time directly:

   ```
   [[1331028000000, 5], [1331031600000, 6], [1331035200000, 4]]
   ```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp5GA/)

Comment: the only input that worked for me was directly inputting the epock time directly. thanks

Comment: Date.UTC returns epock time, so number i believe that 2 and 3 are basically the same. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @eolsson, epoch time is usually the way to go since technically, Date() objects are javascript, not JSON, and you're unlikely to find an off-the-shelf serializer that generates them.

You'll want to format the date, too, something like this --

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b', this.value*1000); // milliseconds not seconds
    },
  }
}
```

The date formatting is done [php style](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).