# How can I manually feed the inputs of a Highcharts' Master detail chart?

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts, visualization, time-series

I want to use the Highcharts' Master detail chart as visualized here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

However, I don't want to use intervals in order for the script to automatically assign Date values to each point of data, because my data are not necessarily continuous. E.g. I might have data for one minute and nothing for the next minute.

Ideally, I want to visualize three days in this chart. Each point will be a value of a specific minute of a specific date.

Any suggestions how I can do that? I don't mind using other libraries, if that's necessary.

Let me know if I didn't make myself clear or if you need more information.

Thank you.

Comment: You can specify each point as a pair (timestamp, value). See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548326/what-format-does-the-highcharts-js-library-accept-for-dates-in-rails/9580111#9580111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data properties in the series object can except either an array of values, in which case it will assume data to be equally spaced. Alternatively you can pass an array of arrays, where the outer array has size same as number of points, and each element of this array is another array of size 2, with first element as epochTime and the 2nd being the value. There is also a third option as explained below

Documentation @ http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#series--data

Excerpt of the documentation

`data : Array<Mixed>`

An array of data points for the series. The series object is expecting the points to be ordered from low to high. The reason for this is to increase performance. While in many cases the data is fetched from a server, it's also more convenient to sort on the server and thereby save on client resources. The points can be given in three ways:

A list of numerical values. In this case, the numerical values will be interpreted as y values, and x values will be automatically calculated, either starting at 0 and incrementing by 1, or from pointStart and pointInterval given in the plotOptions. Example:

```
data: [0, 5, 3, 5]
```

A list of arrays with two values. In this case, the first value is the x value and the second is the y value. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point, and the x value is incremented following the above rules. Example:

```
data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
```

A list of object with named values. In this case the objects are point configuration objects as seen under options.point. Example:

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

[View JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hw2JL)

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the JSFiddle example, it will save my loads of time. Cheers!