# Highcharts with date and time for x axis (from a database with format YYYYMMDDHHMM)

Tags: php, database, highcharts

I am trying to draw a graph using Highcharts for values with time and date for x axis. My database has the date values as YYYYMMDDHHMM (201409011345) and I want to plot y values with this date and time. my code is as follows ;

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   extract $row;
   $data[] = "[$datetime, $value]"; //here $datetime is like 201405242625 (YYYYMMDDHHMM)
}
?>
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container'
      },
      series: [{
         data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
      }]
});
```

Please give me any suggestions to get the correct datetime values for x axis

Thanks

Comment: What's your actual problem/question?

Comment: Dear John, My question is when I plot the graph using above way, the output graph values are not correct. I checked the 'view source of the output and $data has values as follws; data: [[201409101918, 505],[201409101919, 494],[201409101920, 487],.....

Answer (score 0):

Your date value needs to either be in epoch format, or a Date.UTC object.

I'm not sure how well PHP will understand your date format, but assuming that it can, you can use the strtotime() function.

In you case, it would be

```
$date_stamp = strtotime($datetime) * 1000
```

You need the * 1000 because PHP uses epoch time in seconds, Javascript uses milliseconds.

If PHP has a hard time interpreting your date format, you may need to format it within your database query, or use PHP's substr() function to break it up into its components and rebuild a readable date format.

References:

- http://www.epochconverter.com/
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- [How to list dates (day-by-day) on xAxis using HighCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212785/how-to-list-dates-day-by-day-on-xaxis-using-highcharts/24219811#24219811)

Comment: I tried $date_stamp = strtotime($datetime) * 1000 and now the graph  is shown correctly but still the poiting values are not correct;

Comment: I tried as @jlbriggs method and now the output graph is correct but, there is a shift in the x axis. example:my data set is as follows, 201409101918 505
201409101919 494
201409101920 487
201409101921 487
but the graph shows 20140910191 as Wednesday,Sept,10 17.18 (with UTC format 1410369480000) > Please help me to correct this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is the correct date/time for time stamp 1410369480000. Can you create a fiddle demonstrating the problem you are having?

Comment: @jibriggs  1410369480000 is GMT. But Imy requirement is to get the time for local time zone(GMT +5.5). Although I tried //$timezone = 'Asia/Colombo'; $date_stamp = strtotime($datetime, $timezone) * 1000;  still the output related to GMT. How to achieve local time. Sorry for the confusion, Thanks

Comment: Oh, right: set the global useUTC property to false - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC