# Highcharts showing time instead of date

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
          type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
          text: 'Test Progress'
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        },
        type: "datetime"
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Grade'
          }
      },
      credits: { enabled: false },
      series: [{

        data: [[1331028000000, 5], [1331031600000, 6], [1331035200000, 4]]
      }]
  });
});
```

By following this thread, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548326/what-format-does-the-highcharts-js-library-accept-for-dates`

it says that i can input the dates in the above way inside data but it shows time instead of date.

Also i tried the first method and still gives me time. How can i display dates?

Also i am trying to get the dates from records and display them there, in what format do i need to convert them to properly show them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering here is the query i have come up with

`Test.where("user_id = ?", 25).order('created_at DESC').select(:grade,:created_at).map { |g| [ g.created_at.to_i * 1000, g.grade.to_i ] }.inspect`

i wrapped this query in a method and called the method in view

```
series: [{

        data: <%= grades %>
      }]
```

this creates this line of code

`data: [[1454777030000, 25], [1454598308000, 50], [1454598191000, 75], [1454163373000, 100], [1454163332000, 100], [1454163177000, 100], [1454163000000, 0], [1454096412000, 50], [1454096220000, 50], [1454095875000, 0], [1454095853000, 50], [1454082249000, 22], [1454081128000, 100], [1453037445000, 100]]`

which seems to work with highcharts